# please help in python numpy "could not convert string to float"

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

In my class, we are only allowed to use numpy. so using pandas will not help. I keep getting this error:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
datastr = np.loadtxt('oasis_longitudinal.csv' , delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=(5,7,8,10,11), dtype='str') 
datastr[ datastr=='"Demented"']=1
datastr[ datastr=='"Converted"']=1
datastr[ datastr=='"Nondemented"']=0
datastr[ datastr=='"M"']=1
datastr[ datastr=='"F"']=0
data = np.array(datastr, dtype='float')
data = np.array(datastr, dtype='float')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-b10e624df1ce> in <module>
      7 datastr[ datastr=='"M"']=1
      8 datastr[ datastr=='"F"']=0
----> 9 data = np.array(datastr, dtype='float')
     10 data = np.array(datastr, dtype='float')

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'M'
```

Here is also the data

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please also include the data.

Comment: Try just `"M"` instead of `'"M"'`

Comment: The same for other strings.And provide a sample of what has been read by *np.loadtxt*.